# ¿Como cambiar estilo de un listview?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Buenas me gustaria saber como cambiar el tamaño y color del texto que aparece en un listview en android, lo necesito ya que mi fondo quiero que sea un azul claro y me muesta las letras en blanco y con un tamaño muy pequeño, con lo cual no se llegan a percibir correctamente.

Utilizo java a la hora de programar la aplicacion, este codigo es lo que e intentado por ahora que no me a dado error pero tampoco me a cambiado nada

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/foodList"
    android:layout_width="404dp"
    android:layout_height="537dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTitle"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/linearLayoutCompat" />
```

Comment: podrias poner lo que has intentado? creo que buscar un custom adapter

Comment: Hola, recuerda que es importante agregar lo que estas realizando, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez puede ser un custom adapter, e estado buscando y la gente crea ficheros xml en los cuales guardar textview pero a mi me da error, e intentado cambiarle las propiedades en el xml del activitymain pero no he conseguido nada

Comment: coloca lo que has intentado para ayudarte mejor

Comment: listo ya e puesto lo ultimo que e intentado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes modificar el texto directamente en el ListView, debes crear una vista personalizada para poder modificarlo. Puedes crear un .xml con un TextView que te permita modificar el texto:

Por ejemplo **row.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="El texto que quieras"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTitle"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Despues creas un adaptador para el ListView y utilizas esa vista personalizada que creaste para poder crear el ListView. Si lo que vas a mostrar es solo texto puede usar una [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter)

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Contexto_de_la_Activity,
                       R.layout.row, lo_que_utilizaras_para_llenar_el_ListView);

miListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

como has estado?

Has intentado usar una celda custom para tu ListView? Podrías personalizar el estilo de tus celdas todo lo que quieras. Son muchos pasos mas, pero te aseguras que tu celda sea exactamente como tu quieres.

Podria recomendarte ademas que uses un RecyclerView en lugar de un ListView? Podrias ahorrarte algunos problemas en el futuro, ya que el recycler view adapter usa un el view holder pattern. 
Puedes encontrar mas informacion de los beneficios aqui: 
[RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570325/what-are-recyclerview-advantages-compared-to-listview)

No deberias hacer muchos cambios en tu xml quedaria asi:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/foodList"
    android:layout_width="404dp"
    android:layout_height="537dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="152dp"/>
```

Primero deberias crear un nuevo layout, a mi personalmente me gusta llamarlos "list_item_etc", por lo que veo, en tu caso seria, "list_item_food"
Deberias cambiar las dimensiones y colores de este codigo por las dimensiones y colores que tu necesites!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/food_cell_height"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
          android:id="@+id/list_item_food_name"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:textColor="@color/white"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text_size"
          android:background="@color/blue"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Bien, ahora que tienes creado el xml, necesitas crear un custom adapter:

```
public class FoodListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodListAdapter.FoodListHolder> {
    /** For testing*/
    @SuppressWarnings("unused") private static final String TAG = FoodListAdapter.class.getName();
    private List<String> foodNames;

    static class FoodListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final AppCompatTextView foodName;

        FoodListHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.foodName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_food_name);            
        }
    }

    FoodListAdapter(List<String> foodNames){
       this.foodNames = foodNames;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FoodListHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_food, parent, false);
        return new FoodListHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodListHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.foodName.setText(this.foodNames.get(position));
    }
}
```

Bien, ahora necesitas usar tu custom adapter. Para eso, tienes que hacerle a esa lista que pusiste como ejemplo, un setAdapter. No se si tienes esa lista en una Activity o en un Fragment. Voy a asumir que esta en una Activity para el ejemplo, luego tu deberias adaptarlo a tu codigo!

```
public class FoodActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /** For testing*/
    @SuppressWarnings("unused") private static final String TAG = FoodActivity.class.getName();

    private RecyclerView foodList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_food);//Donde esta tu list view.
        this.foodList = this.findViewById(R.id.foodList);
        this.foodList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getApplicationContext())); //Esto es importante a la hora de usar un RecyclerView
        this.initialize();
    }

    private void initialize(){
       List<String> foodNames = new ArrayList();
       foodNames.add("Pizza");
       foodNames.add("Paella");
       this.foodList.setAdapter(new FoodListAdapter(foodNames));
    }
}
```

Si bien es una forma mas dificil de implementar, creo que es una mejor solucion.
Si tienes alguna duda no dudes en preguntar, ya que, estoy usando algunos elementos de la librerias de compatibilidad que tal vez necesites implementar en tu proyecto, si no sabes como hacerlo puedo decirte.

Un saludo!